# Non "once saved always saved" doctrines?

Tags: assurance-of-salvation

I am a confused person in regards to what is biblical (not wanting people's opinions), in regards to what the biblically supported doctrines are for non "once saved always saved" doctrines, as I don't know a lot about this area.

I think at present that this article clears up my confusion at least as far as I currently understand.

https://gracethrufaith.com/topical-studies/tough-questions-answered/does-god-call-everyone/

Comment: Sorry, there's a lot here, could you focus in on one clear question?

Comment: It seems to me, and it is just my own impression, that what you need is to be taught the gospel by someone sent of God. I never figured things out for myself (fifty years ago when I was converted) but I received the gospel from one who ministered Christ to my soul. I left home and moved from Scotland to England to receive that ministry. You are asking the same kind of questions that puzzled me half a century ago. May God be your guide.

Comment: @curiousdannii I did clarify, by asking for non-once saved always saved doctrines (their names) and no ridiculous ones. And the Gospel in one persons opinion is different in anothers , and it seems God has led me from evangelising with tracts, to an issue with exact doctrine confusion, stopping me use tracts and with the "standard" "once saved doctrine" etc.  So which doctrine is correct and biblical? Not a Calvinist or Arminian opinion etc?

Comment: @dave44 I agree, there is a lot here. Multiple different topics, the Biblical definition of sin, pre-destination, once saved always saved, faith vs works. I would say these are each good for their own question. Below I answered the question of once saved, always saved; as this is what you alluded to in the title.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "once saved, always saved" doctrine.  The whole idea of Calvinism is that while you might be among the elect, you won't know it until the end of your life.  If you were to turn from a faithful Christian to a mass murderer in your last days of life, the Arminian would say that you lost your salvation.  The Calvinist would say that you never had it in the first place.  (I'm not a Calvinist, but I know that "once saved, always saved" is not an accurate representation of Calvinist doctrine.)

Comment: There's no way to definitively identify "what is Biblical" - opinions about the Bible are inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

Many errors and theological schisms have come from a misunderstanding of what election is, how it applies, and how it differs from predestination.

Election is according to God's foreknowledge (1 Peter 1:2), it is not a divinely exclusive choice by God, wherein He chooses to save some and hinders others from believing.  Election is simply a term describing how God has known the end from the beginning as regards the individual, eternal destiny of each person:  He knew whether or not each individual human would believe before He created.  The invitation to be reconciled to God through the Gospel of Jesus Christ is equally available to all.  No one battles God trying to come to faith while God resists Him.

Predestination involves those who have already believed being conformed to the image of the Lord Jesus Christ through the sanctifying work of the Holy Spirit living in them ([Romans 8:28-30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%208%3A28-30&version=ESV)).  Predestination does not mean that God enables some to believe and not others.  Predestination means that those who have believed are irrevocably locked into the process of being conformed to the image of Christ.  The process is not painless (Romans 7) but [it will be carried on until completion](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Phillipians%201%3A6&version=ESV).  The ground of assurance lies here and it is a firm foundation.

> For those whom he foreknew he also predestined to be conformed to the image of his Son, in order that he might be the firstborn among many brothers.  And those whom he predestined he also called, and those whom he called he also justified, and those whom he justified he also glorified. - Romans 8:29-30

Can it be that Almighty God has predestined a person for something (conforming to the image of His Son, in this case) and that person can then foil His eternal purpose by failing to endure?  It is hard to imagine the Apostle Paul not being sure that the Lord would preserve him in his faith and bring him into glory.

> But I am not ashamed, for **I know** whom I have believed, and **I am convinced** that **he is able to guard** until that day what has been entrusted to me. - 2 Timothy 1:12

It can be a slippery slope to trust solely in what Christ has done for one's reconciliation and then trust in one's own effort to remain in Him.  He is the One who saves and He is the one who keeps and He doeth all things well.

> Let me ask you only this: Did you receive the Spirit by works of the law or by hearing with faith? Are you so foolish? Having begun by the Spirit, are you now being perfected by the flesh? - Galatians 3:2-3

Comment: The issue with this is that it requires someone to stay in Christ to be saved, as Jesus/God will save all in Christ, but I see no verse that poses a certain salvation until the end, because there is a sin unto death, even those who have "tasted of the spirit" etc, can fall away etc.  So "eternal security" or "once saved always saved" seems at odds with many verses, even in revelation with "luc-warm" Christians being spat out etc (or are they never saved, how can one tell?).  Why fear if we are eternally saved?  = Non-once saved always saved doctrines, and not opinions (God starts the universe)

Comment: Your theory is in contradiction to _According as he hath chosen us in him before the foundation of the world, that we should be holy and without blame before him in love:_ Ephesians 1:4. 'Chosen' is not the foreseeing of who would do the choosing.It is the active intention of the Father who begets.

Comment: it says chosen us IN HIM, not outside of HIM. Does this suggest those in Jesus Christ as believers and not those outside, already knowing believers who would choose themselves, but God chose to save those who accept Jesus before the foundation?

Comment: The idea that salvation can be lost is also at odds with many verses.  We have a deposit guaranteeing our inheritance...God will complete the good work He began in us...those He foreknew He predestined, called, justified, and GLORIFIED...we are seated with Christ in heavenly places...we are born again of incorruptible seed...etc.  Personally, I dare not place my faith in my own ability to endure.  I would rather look to Him who is able to present me faultless before the presence of His glory - Jude 1:24.

Comment: @NigelJ Would you say that you had no choice in coming to faith?  According to Romans 8 foreknowledge and predestination to be conformed to Christ come before calling.

Comment: @dave44 The first chapter of Ephesians, up through verse 14, builds up rather than speaks against assurance of salvation.  We **have obtained** an inheritance and we have been given a deposit guaranteeing that inheritance until we take possession of it.

Comment: @MikeBorden It was against my natural inclinations that I was drawn. Initially, there was a massive resistance. And reluctance. And ignorance. And despair. Yet now, as the decades have past, all I desire is what I am given, freely. Choice ? Well, I am grateful, yes. But none of this is my doing or my initiative. It is not of man, nor could I have achieved any of this. Never. It is totally contrary to what I am, naturally and by birth. The love of Christ constrains, nevertheless. And all the glory is His, absolutely.

Comment: @NigelJ I am in your camp.  So I can't help but think that what appears to us as irresistible grace is nothing more than God's foreknowledge playing itself out in real time.

Comment: @NigelJ I get the point of Jesus saving and doing it all and none of it being me, but your point of foreknowing & predestination before calling suggests that anyone who accepts Jesus in the future will be conformed to the image of Jesus Christ because everyone in Christ is predestined to be conformed and foreknown. But not everyone is forced to accept Jesus Christ even though the Father CALLS-ALL to repentance, not some.  If He calls all, then are you suggesting that God calls people who cannot accept salvation, that seems a bit twisted. Am I wrong?

Comment: @dave44 _Moreover whom he did predestinate, them he also called: and whom he called, them he also justified: and whom he justified, them he also glorified._ [Romans 8:30 KJV]. He predestinated them, he called them, he justified them and he glorified them. I cannot see any problem in this. It is as plain as plain can be.

Comment: @NigelJ I currently think this cleared things up for me, as far as I can tell.  https://gracethrufaith.com/topical-studies/tough-questions-answered/does-god-call-everyone/

Answer (score 1):

This is from the SDA perspective, as we do NOT believe in once saved always saved.

### 1. The believer in Christ must endure until the end to be saved.

If once you are "saved" you are always saved, what would be the point of endurance? What would be the point of remaining steadfast in the faith?

> Blessed is the man **that endureth temptation**: for when he is tried, he
>   **shall receive the crown of life**, which the Lord hath promised to them
>   that love him.
>
> James 1:12

James here is writing to a group of believers, as he calls them "my brethren" in verse 2. It is also interesting that the Bible says they SHALL receive the crown of life, and not that they have already received it.

Jesus speaking about the end times, which is very relevant today (read all of Matthew 24), says,

> But he that shall endure unto the end, the same shall be saved.
>
> Matthew 24:36

Notice that it says shall be saved, and not he who IS saved will endure to the end. Jesus says the same in Matthew 10: 22, 23.

> He that hath an ear, let him hear what the Spirit saith unto the
>   churches; **To him that overcometh** will I give to eat of the tree of
>   life, which is in the midst of the paradise of God.
>
> Revelation 2:7

There is so overcoming that must be done, for those who will be in the paradise of God.

### 2. There are backsliders or those who draw back.

If once saved always saved, there would be no one who draws back or backsliders, as that would be impossible. That's not what the Bible teaches.

> For you have need of **endurance, so that after you have done the will
>   of God**, you may receive the promise: “For yet a little while, And He
>   who is coming will come and will not tarry. Now the just shall live by
>   faith; **But if anyone draws back**, My soul has no pleasure in him.”
>   **But we are not of those who draw back to perdition**, but of those who believe to the saving of the soul.
>
> Hebrews 10:36-39

Once again, the theme of endurance. Its is important to note that God explicitly speaks of those who "draw back" and the author of Hebrews speaks of those who "draw back to perdition". If someone draws back to perdition, it means they were once heading in the opposite way, toward salvation.

> For if **after they have escaped the pollutions of the world** through the
>   knowledge of the Lord and Saviour Jesus Christ, they are **again
>   entangled** therein, and overcome, the latter end is worse with them
>   than the beginning. For it had been better for them not to have known
>   the way of righteousness, than, after they have known it, **to 
>   turn from the holy commandment** delivered unto them. But it is happened unto them
>   according to the true proverb, The dog is turned to his own vomit
>   again; and the sow that was washed to her wallowing in the mire.
>
> 2 Peter 2:20-22

Though graphic, the apostle Peter clearly shows that a person can escape the world and again be entangled in it. This is completely contrary to the "once saved, always saved" doctrine.

### 3. Biblical Examples

There are examples all throughout the Bible of those who were believers and were used by God, only to have turned away and be lost.

Among those are King Saul, whom the Holy Ghost fell upon and prophecied, only to be used later by Satan to kill the prophets of God, and ultimately kill himself. (1 Samuel 10:11, 1 Samuel 19:23, 1 Samuel 22:17, 1 Samuel 31)

There is also Balaam, who was a prophet of God, and blessed Israel, even prophecying of the coming Messiah (Numbers 24:17). Yet his love for riches overcame him and he was killed while going against Israel and ultimately against God. (Numbers 31:8, 16)

Finally, there is the case of Judas. He walked with Jesus, heard the words of Jesus, preached for Jesus, was given authority by Jesus to "drive out impure spirits and to heal every disease and sickness." (Matthew 10:1) Yet his love of money and power drove him to betray the very Son of God and ultimately, kill himself.

For a deeper read, see ["Once Saved, Always Saved?"](https://www.amazingfacts.org/news-and-features/inside-report/magazine/id/14710/t/once-saved--always-saved-)

Comment: There is no inherent contradiction between the call to endurance and receiving our ability to endure from God.  Jude 1:24

Comment: @MikeBorden While I completely agree that we do receive our ability to endure from the Lord, the main difference is we have the choice to act on it or not. With the "once saved, always saved" doctrine you do not have a choice. Backsliders have that choice, and chose not to endure. Do you believe backsliders then, were not given the ability to endure from God?

Comment: I think that backsliders start from the position of faith in themselves, which is, perhaps, not faith at all.